# The arbitrary product of completely regular spaces is completely regular.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> The topological product of completely regular spaces is completely regular.

I am aware of the question [Product of two completely regular spaces is completely regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579216/product-of-two-completely-regular-spaces-is-completely-regular), and it turns out that my attempt ends up being analogous to what was done there (but for an arbitrary product). However, I have some questions about a few parts of my proof.

**My proof:**
Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of completely regular spaces; *i.e.* each $X_i$ is a $T_1$ space for which the following holds: given any point $x_i \in X_i$, and given any neighborhood $U_i$ of that point, there exists a continuous function 
$$ f_i:X_i \rightarrow [0,1] \\ x_i \mapsto 0 \\ y \in U_i^c, y\mapsto1 $$
Let $x=(x_i)\in X$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$.
since $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, there exists an open neighborhood $v$ of $x$ such that $v\subseteq U$. $v$ must be the union of elements of the basis of the product topology. So $v=\underset{\lambda}{\bigcup} \underset{i}{\prod}Q_i^\lambda$, where the $Q_i^\lambda$ are open sets of $X_i$ and only a finite number of them are different from $X_i$.
We can define a function 
$$
f:X \rightarrow [0,1] \\ x \mapsto \underset{i}{\prod}f_i(x_i)
$$
where 
$$ f_i:X_i \rightarrow [0,1] \\ x_i \mapsto 0 \\ y \in (Q_i^\lambda)^c, y\mapsto1 $$
which we can choose to be continuous by complete regularity of the $X_i$. Notice that we can have a different function $f_i$ for each set of $\lambda$s.
First, we note that $f(x)=\underset{i}{\prod}f_i(x_i)=0$.
We still have to check that $f$ is continuous and that $f(y)=1$ for any $y\in U^c$.
Let $V$ be an open set of $[0,1]$. We have 
$$
f^{\dashv}(V)=\underset{i}{\prod} f_i^\dashv(V) 
$$
and by continuity of the $f_i$ this is a product of open sets of the $X_i$  and hence is open in $X$.
[**First Question:** is this true? It doesn't seem to be: if an infinite number of open sets in the product are different from $X_i$, then the product is not an open set of $X$, I think...]
This establishes the continuity of $f$.
Now, let $y\in X-U$. We have 
$$
X-U \subseteq X-v = X-\underset{\lambda}{\bigcup} \underset{i}{\prod}Q_i^\lambda = \underset{\lambda}{\bigcap} (X-\underset{i}{\prod}Q_i^\lambda)
$$
So $y$ belongs to all sets $X-\underset{i}{Q_i^\lambda}$ and so all the $y_i$ are in $(Q_i^\lambda)^c$ for some $\lambda$. Choosing those $\lambda$ in our definition of the functions $f_i$ we get $f(y)=\underset{i}{\prod}f_i(y)=1$.  $\square$
[**Second Question:** is this last argument sound? It is not very clear to me].

Comment: Is $f$ an infinite product? This is not needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How come? What should I use then?

Comment: See my answer. It reduces to a finite product.

Comment: Ok. But before I dismiss my attempt all together, can you tell me the answer to my second question? If the last argument is sound, my only problem is continuity?

Comment: You could salvage it by using only the real functions for the finitely many coordinates and constantly 1 functions everywhere else.  This makes it well-defined as a product and also continuous. But the last bit still requires some argument. My way is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general answer in terms of initial topologies can be found [in this answer by Stefan Hemcke](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1579853/4280).

Another slightly generalised answer: 
let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subbase for the a topological space $X$. Then $X$ is completely regular iff

$$\forall S \in \mathcal{S}: \forall x \in S: \exists f: X \rightarrow [0,1] \text{ continuous: } f(x) = 0 \land f[X\setminus S] = \{1\}$$

The necessity is obvious as subbase sets are open. For sufficiency: suppose $O$ is open and $p \in O$. Then there are subbasic elements $S_1, \ldots S_n \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $p \in \bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i \subset O$.

For each $i = 1,\ldots n$ find $f_i$ as promised for $p$ and $S_i$.
Then $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $f(x) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - f_i(x)) $ is continuous (as addition and multiplication are continuous  on the reals) 
and $f(p) = 0$ (all the product terms are $1$) and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \notin \bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i$ (then one of $f_i$ becomes $1$, so the product becomes $0$ and so $f$ becomes 1).
So  $f$ is as required for $O$ and $p$.

This directly applies to products, as there we have a subbase of the form $S= p_i^{-1}[O]$ for $O$ open in $X_i$, and $p_i$ the projection from the product onto its $i$-th coordinate. If then $p$ is in $S$, then $p_i(p) \in O$, and we have an $g_i$ there for $p_i(p)$ and $O$ as $X_i$ is completely regular, and then $g = f \circ p_i$ is as required for $S$ as well. This is slightly easier on the notation, I think.