# Product of induced topologies and induced product topology coincide?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces, $A\subset X, B\subset Y$. I have to prove that the following two topologies on $A\times B$ coincide:

The product of the topology of $A$ (induced from $X$) and that of $B$ (induced from $Y$),

and the topology induced on $A\times B$ from the product topology on $X\times Y$.

Intuitively, I know this is correct. But how do I prove this mathematically correct?

Thank you!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280 proves a more general statement.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't understand which part of that proof is answer to my question..

Comment: At the end (products and subspaces), as an application of the transitive law of initial topologies.

Answer (score 2):

$(U \cap A) \times (V \cap B) = (U \times V) \cap (A \times B)$ (where $U$ open in $X$, $V$ open in $Y$) is a key identity here. The right hand side describes a base for the subspace topology for $A \times B$, the left hand side a base for the product topology of the subspace topologies. So the topologies share a base and are identical.