# Definition of the topology on the inverse limit

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I just want to make sure that I have the topology on the inverse limit correctly as I am having quite a bit of difficulty understanding this.
If $\lim_{\leftarrow i \in I} A_i$ is some inverse limit then the topology on it is the coarsest collection of open sets such that the projection
$$
\varprojlim_{i \in I} A_i \rightarrow A_j
$$
is continuous for each $j \in I$.
This is my understanding. Could I possibly verify this with someone because I just can't find anywhere that spells it out.

Comment: Yes, that's right, same as the product topology.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: Aside: `\varprojlim` formats as $\varprojlim$. (the name, I think, should be read as short for "variant: projective limit")

Answer (score 4):

An inverse limit is a subspace of a product, and topologised as such. It's an initial topology itself by the associativity of initial topologies, using the restricted projections as you mention. This fact is mentioned at the end of [my long post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280) that explains a lot of things about initial topologies (product topologies and subspace topologies are its best-known examples).

Comment: This was sort of thing that I could find when I looked up Wikipedia for example, but I was hoping for something without all the terminologies like initial topology ...