# Characteristic property of disjoint union spaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, alternative-proof, solution-verification

Suppose $(X_j)_{j\in J}$ is an indexed family of topological space and $Y$ is a topological space.

$f: \coprod _{j\in J}X_j$ $\rightarrow Y$ is continuous $\iff$  The restriction of $f$ to each $X_j$ is continuous.

My Attempt:

Suppose $f$ is continuous. Let j$\in J$ and $U$ be open in $Y$. Then $f|_{X_j}^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)\cap X_j$ is open in $Y$, since $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the disjoint union space.

For the converse, let $V$ be open in $Y$. Since the restriction of $f$ to each $X_j$ is continuous, it follows that for each $j\in J$, $f|_{X_j}^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)\cap X_j$ is open in $X_j$ which happens if and only $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the disjoint union.

Is the proof correct? (Please answer this question)

Comment: What about $f:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1)$ and $g(x)=x$ for all $x \in [1,2]$? The individual functions are continuous over their domains, but the combined function is discontinuous over the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: @Michael The topology on your union is not the disjoint union (or coproduct) topology though. If you did take that topology, the combined function would be continuous.

Comment: @Michael that's not a disjoint union/coproduct topology on $[0,2]$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma In the disjoint union topology, all summands most be open, but $[1, 2]$ is not open in $[0, 2]$, so this is not the topological coproduct (which is what is meant by disjoint union) of $[0, 1)$ and $[1, 2]$.

Comment: @Hennno Brandsma No problem

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : You are allowed to delete redundant comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct. It follows directly, as you say, from the characterisation of open sets in $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j$:

$$ O \subseteq \coprod_{j \in J} X_j \text{ open } \iff \forall j \in J: O \cap X_j \text { open in } X_j$$

which is in itself a consequence of the fact that $\coprod_{j \in J} X_j$ has the final topology w.r.t. the set of standard inclusion-embeddings $\{e_j: X_j \to \coprod_{j \in J} X_j \}$. It's in fact an instance of what I call [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813473/4280) *the universal theorem of continuity of final topologies*, which characterises final topologies. Note that $f \circ e_j = f\restriction_{X_j}$, in essence.

Comment: I dont think my last sentence is correct though, because if $f^{-1}(U) \cap X_j$ is open in $X_j$ , its equal to $U’ \cap X_j$ where U is open in the disjoint union that doesnt mean the preimage of U is equal to U’, which is what i was thinking at the time.  But your last sentence fixes that, I think.

Comment: Hello, may you please elaborate on the converse of the theorem? I would very much like to see how you would approach it, please.

Comment: @topologicalmagician the link in the post (long!) has a proof.