# What does this problem want to teach us and how to prove it?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The problem is:

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $Y$ be a set (without a topology as yet), and suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function (of sets).

1. Show that $Y$ has a unique largest topology for which $f$ is
   continuous.
2. Show that with this topology, a function $g: Y \rightarrow Z $ from
   $Y$ to some other topological space is continuous iff $g \circ f: X
   \rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

**My question is:**

1- What does this problem want to teach us and how to prove it?

Comment: It is defining the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology). For (a) define $U\subset Y$ to be open iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Check that this collection of sets is a topology on $Y$. It is clear that you cannot add any more subsets of $Y$ to it without making $f$ discontinuous.

Comment: Answers can be found [in this post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813473/4280) about final topologies in general. Yours is a special case.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed at least in (a), @supinf

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why mine is a special case?

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy why we defined $U$ by this way? Is not this the definition of the continuity of $f$, but  $X$ and $Y$ should be topological spaces in thayt definition. why it is clear that I cannot add any more subsets of $Y$ without makinf $f$ discontinuous?

Comment: The definition of the open sets of $Y$ look like the definition of continuity for $f$ exactly because that is goal; to build a topology such that $f$ is continuous and moreover call open as many subsets of $Y$ as possible.

Comment: You cannot add any more subsets because if you add a set $V\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open in $X$, then by definition $f$ wouldn't be continuous.

Comment: Is this because yours contain $Y_{i}$ but mine contains one $Y$ only? but my $Y$ is just a set, it is not a topological space  @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think your post answers only part (a) .... am I correct?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think the part of your answer that answers my (a) is existence theorem for final topologies ... am I correct?

Comment: It answers both. The characterisation of continuity is also there. And because we only have one map instead of a family it’s a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wants to show that is a natural way to endow a set $Y$ with a topology when we have a function $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ already has a topology. This obeys a nice *universal property* (your $2$.) and is essentially unique with that property.

There also is a unique *smallest* topology that makes $f$ continuous but this will always be the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset, Y\}$ and says nothing of interest about $f$, really.

For existence: just check the axioms of topology for

$$\mathcal{T}=\{O \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[O] \text{ open in } X\}$$

using identities like $$f^{-1}[\bigcup_i O_i]=\bigcup_i f^{-1}[O_i]$$ and similar ones for intersection, plus the fact that $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ and $f^{-1}[Y]=X$ for any map $f:X \to Y$ too.

This obeys 1. because if $\mathcal{T}'$ is any arbitrary topology on $Y$ that makes $f$ continuous, then for all $O \in \mathcal{T}'$ we have that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ (by that assumed continuity!) and so *by definition*, $O \in \mathcal{T}$, hence $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ has been shown and $\mathcal{T}$ is maximal as required.

Now if $g: Y \to Z$ is continuous, then $g \circ f$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions.

Conversely, if $g: Y \to Z$ is a function such that $g \circ f$ is continuous, let $O$ be open in $Z$. Then by the assumed continuity $$(g \circ f)^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[O]]$$ is open in $X$ and thus by definition of $\mathcal{T}$ again we have $g^{-1}[O] \in \mathcal{T}$. As $O$ was arbitrary, $g$ is continuous.

Comment: If you have time could u look at the same above question but with arrows turned around https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507131/show-that-f-has-a-unique-smallest-topology-for-which-f-is-continuous

Comment: @Secretly that’s the dual statement, also in category theory sense.

Comment: Could you please look at this question (if you have time) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518158/the-sum-of-two-sets-and-the-disjoint-union ?