# Show that $X$ has a unique smallest topology for which $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The question is:

Let $X$ be a set (without a topology as yet), let $Y$ be a topological space, and suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function (of sets).

1. Show that $X$ has a unique smallest topology for which $f$ is
   continuous.
2. Show that with this topology, a function $g: W \rightarrow X $ from
    some topological space $W$ to $X$ is continuous iff $f \circ g: W
   \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to generate this topology ?

Comment: What do you know about the preimage under $f$ of open sets of $Y$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, the inverse image of every open set is open @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\mathcal{T}_X=\{f^{-1}[O]: O \subseteq Y \text{ open }\}$ and note
that this is a topology on $X$ by the standard identities

$$f^{-1}[\bigcup_{i \in I} O_i]=\bigcup_{i \in I} f^{-1}[O_i]$$

and

$$f^{-1}[\bigcap_{i \in I} O_i]=\bigcap_{i \in I} f^{-1}[O_i]$$

Minimality is trivial: if $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology such that $f$ is continuous as a map $(f:X,\mathcal{T}) \to Y$, for each set of the form $f^{-1}[O]$ with $O$ open in $Y$, $f^{-1} \in \mathcal{T}$ by continuity.
So $\mathcal{T}_X \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ has the required minimality.

And for 2. one direction follows from compositions of continuous functions being continuous and the other is not too hard either: if $(f \circ g): W \to Y$ is continuous then if $U$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_X$, so $U=f^{-1}[O]$ with $O$ open in $Y$, then

$$g^{-1}[U]= g^{-1}[f^{-1}[U]]=(f \circ g)^{-1}[O]$$

and the right hand side is open by continuity of $f \circ g$. So $g$ is continuous.

It's the exact dual proof to your earlier question on the final topology.

Comment: I am sorry if this trivial but I am confused about the proof of minimality, could you show it please?

Comment: Could you please describe the other direction of 2. where you used a subbase as I can not see it.

Comment: why its proof is not the same as the previous question?

Comment: @Secretly I improved the post, realised that I don't need a subbase when we have but one map, while for general initial topologies (based on more maps, like projections on a product) we do. This simplifies the proofs a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology):

$\{ f^{-1}(U) : U\text{ open within }Y \}$