# The sum of two sets and the disjoint union.

Tags: category-theory

I have the following question:

> [image]
>   [image]

For(a) but I do not know how to show practically (using the givens) that $in_{S}$ must be injective, could anyone help me in doing so?

For(b),(c) I do not know how to prove them , could anyone help me in doing so please?

Also, I do not understand what is the importance of $in_{S}$ and $in_{T}$ being injective in defining the disjoint union, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Hint for (a): to show that $in_S$ must be injective, take $U$ to equal $S$ and take $f$ to be the identity map. Hint for (b): take $U=\{0,1\}$, take $f$ to be identically $0$, and take $g$ to be identically $1$. Hint for (c): take $U=S\cup T$ with the obvious inclusion maps $f$ and $g$.

Comment: For (a), Is this a proof using Category theory? not using the ordinary definition of injection?  and why we proof in the way you mentioned? is there a special lesson that the problem is teaching us by using this way? @GregMartin

Comment: I imagine the problem is intended to assess one's ability to interpret and work with fundamental-property definitions. Without knowing the context in which you encountered it, it's impossible to be sure. My proposed proof uses the ordinary definition of an injective function, along with the definitions involved with the fundamental-property diagram—for example, we are given a fixed set called $S\sqcup T$ and fixed set maps $in_S$ and $in_T$, and we can choose any $f,g,U$ we want and be assured that there exists a unique central function called $(f,g)$.

Comment: What do you mean by fundamental property diagram? @GregMartin

Comment: I'll end with the following advice: from your remarks, it seems to me that your current difficulty isn't really with trying to solve the problems (a)–(c), but actually with understanding the definition given in the problem before part (a). It will be important to fully understand that definition (perhaps using similar definitions involving "fundamental properties" that you've already seen), before trying to solve any of the problems involving that definition. That will be time well spent, because understanding definitions is a very important part of doing math!

Comment: So, the idea is that every time you choose any $f$, $g$, and $U$ that diagram must commute, so you are going to prove part (a), (b), and (c) by choosing appropriate maps $f$, $g$ and the set $U$. For example, to show part (a) that $in_S$ is injective, consider the left side of the diagram where you choose $U = S$ and $f = id$. Write down the composition of the maps and obtain the desired [Remember, a map $F$ is injective if $F(a) = F(b)$, then $a = b$; how to check this using the commutativity of the diagram].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exercise is all about finding tricky $U, f, g$ and using the "fundamental" property (I guess a fundamental property is almost a universal property?), eg :

- a) **$in_{S}$ is injective**
  As the only map $\emptyset \mapsto X$ is injective, WLOG $S\neq \emptyset$.
  We use the following (easy) claim : if $v \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
  Take $U = S$, $f = \operatorname{Id}_S$, and $g : T \mapsto S$ any map (there is such a map since $S\neq \emptyset$).
  We have $(f, g) \circ in_S = \operatorname{Id}_S$, which is injective. Hence, $in_S$ is injective.
- b) $\operatorname{Im}(in_S) \cap \operatorname{Im}(in_T) = \emptyset$
  Assume for contradiction that there is $x \in \operatorname{Im}(in_S) \cap \operatorname{Im}(in_T)$.
  Consider $U := \{0, 1\}$, $f$ the constant $0$ map $S \mapsto U$, and $g$ the constant $1$ map $S \mapsto U$.
  Since $(f, g) \circ in_S = f$ we must have $(f, g)(x) = 0$.
  But since $(f, g) \circ in_T = g$ we must have $(f, g)(x) = 1$. Contradiction!
- c) $\operatorname{Im}(in_S) \cup \operatorname{Im}(in_T) = \operatorname{Im}(in_S) \sqcup \operatorname{Im}(in_T)$
  This one is up to you, be creative (and look at @Greg Martin's excellent comment!)  :)

Comment: how injectivity is proved in category theory?

Comment: And how is $in_{T}$ injective?

Comment: Is the hint of @Greg Martin requires any creativity from me? I mean should I prove anything after defining  $U$ and the functions as he said?

Comment: @Emptymind being a monomorphism in Set gives injectivity

Comment: @Henno Brandsma could you please give me a detailed proof of (c)?