# Definition of injective maps in Category theory and the relation of this definition to our ordinary definition.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation, definition, solution-verification

I was reading the answer of letter (a) of this question:

[The sum of two sets and the disjoint union.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518158/the-sum-of-two-sets-and-the-disjoint-union)

but I did not understand it.

**My questions are:**

1-what is the Definition of injective maps in Category theory? and what is the relation of this definition to our ordinary definition (if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x=y$)?

2- Also in the solution, I did not understand this statement "As the only map $\emptyset \mapsto X$ is injective, WLOG $S\neq \emptyset$.
We use the following (easy) claim : if $v \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective. ", could anyone explain it for me please? from where this claim "We use the following (easy) claim : if $v \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective." came?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the question, all the objects are sets and the maps are ordinary functions. The usual definition of injective applies here. If we were in a more general setting, we could ask that the morphism be a [monomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monomorphism). You should prove to yourself that an ordinary function is monomorphic if and only if it's injective.
2. We're trying to prove that a map $S \to X$ is injective. Since every set is empty or non-empty, we only need to check those two cases. For the first case, $S = \emptyset$. Since every map $\emptyset \to X$ is injective, we're done. Then we proceed with the meat of the argument with the $S \neq \emptyset$ case.
3. Have you tried proving this? It's a fairly straightforward application of the the definition of injective.

Comment: for 3. how can I prove it in terms of my ordinary definition?

Comment: what is the letter $v$?

Comment: @Secretly Based on the notation, it's some function whose domain is the same as the codomain of $f$. The choice of letter is irrelevant.

Comment: and why we need a function like $v$? what is its relation to our question?

Comment: I have proved 3

Comment: still, the questions in my before  previous comment are bothering me.

Comment: @Secretly It looks like that short claim is used with $(f, g) \circ in_S = \operatorname{Id}_S$ to show that $in_S$ is injective.

Comment: And what is the intuition behind choosing $U = S$ ? why did he do this?

Comment: ohhh I see, the intuition is that he wanted to use the identity map because he know that the identity map is injective ...... correct?