# Proving that in $S \sqcup T,$ it must be that $S \cup T = S \sqcup T$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, category-theory, solution-verification

I was reading the hints of @GregMartin on solving $(c)$ of this problem [The sum of two sets and the disjoint union.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518158/the-sum-of-two-sets-and-the-disjoint-union)

I am convinced about it. but I am unable to write a proof, could anyone help me in doing so, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question uses sloppy notation. It is not true that $S\cup T=S\sqcup T$ but rather that after identifying $S$ and $T$ with corresponding subsets $\textrm{in}_S(S)$ and $\textrm{in}_T(T)$ we have that
$$
S\sqcup T=\textrm{in}_S(S)\cup \textrm{in}_T(T).
$$

To see why, you can consider the following concrete realization of $S\sqcup T$. It equals the subset of $(S\sqcup T)\times \{1,2\}$ where $S$ is identified with $S\times \{1\}$ and $T$ is identified with $T\times \{2\}$. This construction is known as the "tagged union", where you treat $1$ and $2$ as labels to tell apart the sets $S$ and $T$, even if they intersect originally.

Comment: So what is the proof, could you please describe it to me precisely? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: In the tagged union, $S\sqcup T=(S\times \{1\})\cup (T\times \{2\})$ and $\textrm{in}_S(S)=S\times \{1\}$ and $\textrm{in}_T(T)=T\times \{2\}$. So your statement is true for the tagged union. Now since the $S\sqcup T$ is defined up to unique isomorphism, and this relation does not depend on which isomorphism is chosen, since you have proven it for one such case it must hold for all realizations of the disjoint union.

Comment: why we need that tagged union?

Comment: Is the proof consisting of just choosing the sets and the functions?

Comment: The proof can be given purely abstractly using the universal property of $S\sqcup T$, but since you seem very confused with that I am showing you have the proof goes in one concrete realization of $S\sqcup T$, which (by the universal property) implies the same result holds for any other realization.

Comment: what do you mean by "tell apart" in the line just before last in your answer?

Comment: Let $S=\{0,1\}$ and let $T=\{0,2\}$. Then $S\cup T=\{0,1,2\}$. You can't tell if the $0\in S\cup T$ came from $S$ or from $T$. But in the tagged union $S\sqcup T=\{(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(2,2)\}$ you have two copies of $0$, the one coming from $S$ is tagged $(0,1)$ and the one from $T$ is tagged as $(0,2)$.

Comment: So the proof is to take $U = S\bigcup T$ with $f = in_{S} $ and $g = in_{T} $ .... correct?