# Sub-bases for classical topological constructions

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering whether given a collection of topological spaces $\{(X_\alpha,\tau_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ and sub-bases $\mathcal{S}_\alpha \subset\tau_\alpha$, can we obtain sub-bases from  this sub-bases to classical constructions? I wonder whether these following attempts of giving a sub-base for these constructions is indeed true:

**Sub-space topology:**

Given  a topological space $(X,\tau)$ a sub-base $\mathcal{S}=\{ S_i \}_{i\in I}$ and a subset $G\subset X$, a sub-base for the subspace topology is $\mathcal{S}_G=\{S_i\cap G\}_{i\in I}$.

**Disjoint Union topology:**

The disjoint union of $\{(X_\alpha,  \tau_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ with subases $\{ \mathcal{S}_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$, *has $\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda} \mathcal{S}_\alpha$ a sub-base*.

**Box topology:**

The box topology on $\prod_{\alpha\in \Lambda} X_\alpha$, *has $\prod_{\alpha\in \Lambda}\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ as a sub-base*.

**Product topology**

For all finite $F\subset \Lambda$, I can define $\mathcal{S}_F:=\{U=\prod_\alpha U_\alpha: U_\alpha \in \mathcal{S}_\alpha \; \text{when } \alpha\in F,\; U_\alpha=X_\alpha \; \text{if } \alpha\notin F  \}$, and then *$\mathcal{S}:=\cup_{F\subset \Lambda, \vert F\vert<\infty} \mathcal{S}_F$ is a sub-base for the product topology*.

**Quotient topology:**

Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ with sub-base $\mathcal{S}$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$, then the quotient space $(X/\sim,\tau_{\sim})$ *has $\mathcal{S}_\sim:=\{ [U]_\sim :\; U\in \mathcal{S} \}$ a sub-base*.

This seems true to me, but I have been wrong before so I wanted to verify whether this is true. I should also note that when I say sub-base, it does not have to be a cover.

Comment: @Kevin.S They are all topologies, I was wondering about carrying over generating collections from the original spaces to the appropriate constructions. I proposed generating collections for the constructions. I would be happy to know whether anyone thinks they are not indeed generating collections or verify whether, or perhaps someone has a simpler suggestion to what I attempted.

Comment: So, what you're attempting to do is like this: Given a collection of topological spaces, then apply "operations" (e.g. quotient, product, disjoint union, taking subspace etc.) to one or more than one topological space(s) in the collection. After that, you want to construct a corresponding subbasis in each situation you mentioned or are you saying that you want to construct another subbasis from the given subbasis? (because you mentioned $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ at the beginning of your post)

Comment: I want to construct a corrseponding sub-basis in the "operation"-spaces from originally given sub-basis. Perhaps I should write in italics, the claims I mean to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these constructions are classic examples of so-called *initial topologies* on which I wrote extensively in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280) before.

If $X$ has the initial topology w.r.t. maps $f_i: X \to (X_i, \tau_i), i \in I$ and we have subbases $\mathcal{S}_i$ for each $\tau_i$, then $$\{f_i^{-1}[S]: S \in \mathcal{S}_i\}$$ is a subbase for the initial topology on $X$ w.r.t. the $f_i$. This is an easy combination of the fact of the minimality of $\tau$ and of the fact that each $\tau_i$ is the minimal topology that contaisn $\mathcal{S}_i$, etc.

So for the subspace topology on $ \subseteq X$ this gives $\{S \cap G: S \in \mathcal{S}\}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase on $X$, and for the product topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda} X_\alpha$ we get the more economical subbase

$$\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}[S]: S \in \mathcal{S}_\alpha\}$$

where each such set only depends on one instead of finitely many coordinates.

There is (AFAIK) no such general fact for *final topologies* (of which quotient and sums are examples, see my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813473/4280) e.g.) so there we have to judge case by case.

The box topology is neither initial nor final, but there the situation is indeed as you say: all sets of the form $\prod_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha$, where each $A_\alpha$ is chosen from $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ do form a subbase for the box topology. The proof of this is quite trivial, as products and intersections interact well.

For quotients your idea does *not* work, firstly because $[U]_{\sim}$ (if it is defined as $q[U]$ where $q$ is the canonical quotient map) need not be open (and this is a requirement), and because simple counterexamples exist: Take $X = \Bbb R$ (usual topology) and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation with classes $\Bbb Z$ and $\{x\}, x \notin \Bbb Z$ (so we identify the integers to a point). If we take the countable base as a subbase of $X$ then its images cannot form a subbase for $X{/}{\sim}$ because the latter quotient space does not have a countable base (or subbase) at all (it's well-known that $q(0)$ does not have a countable local base, even).

For sums it's indeed as you state: if we make the necessary identifications  so that each $X_\alpha$ is a real subset of $\oplus_{\alpha \in \Lambda} X_\alpha$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda} \mathcal{S}_\alpha$ is a subbase for that sum, again (as for box products) as sums interact well with intersections.

So in short: your product subbase can be improved upon, the quotient one does not (and cannot) work, and the others are true and have easy proofs.

Comment: Do you think there is a legitimate sub-base induced by the quotient space similar to the other cases?

Comment: And thank you for your thorough answer.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur no not an easy one. You always have to consider this example.