# Uniqueness of the initial topology

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples

The Initial Topology $\tau_X $(as defined below) and its uniqueness is characterised by two certain properties.

I would like to know, what happens to the uniqueness of $\tau_X $, if you remove one or even both properties? Possibly $\tau_X $ is then no longer unique. How would/could such topologies then look like?

Given: A set $X$ and $(Y_i)_{i \in \ I}$ topological spaces and maps $f_i : X \rightarrow Y_i$

There is then an unique topology $\tau_X$ with:

1. All $f_i$ are continuous
2. Given a topological space $Z$ and a map $g: Z \rightarrow X$, then: 
   $g$ continuous $\Leftrightarrow f_i \circ g: Z \rightarrow Y_i $ continuous $\forall i \in I$

$\tau_X$ defined above is called the Initial Topology or the Cofinal Topology with respect to the $f_i$.

Comment: Well, if you do not assume 2, then any topology on $X$ finer than $\tau_X$ is possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you just assume 1. we could just take the discrete topology on $X$ and this would make **all** functions continuous on it.

Usually the initial topology is defined as the intersection of all topologies that make all $f_i$ continuous. This intersection is non-empty (the discrete topology is one of these topologies as we saw) and the intersection of topologies is again a topology. The property 2. then follows, once you observe that we can also say that $X$ is the topology generated by the subbase $\mathcal{S}=\{f_i^{-1}[O]: i \in I, O \subseteq Y_i\}$.

The nice part is that property 2 implies that $X$ must carry this topology. I write more on this in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280).

In fact, property 2. implies property 1, because $g= \mathrm{id}_X$ is always continuous. So just property 2 alone characterises the initial topology.