# Investigating the relationship between $X$ and the inverse limit $\mathcal{L}$ of the tower.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be totally disconnected, compact, metric and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the inverse limit of the sequence. (I mentioned in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620392/verify-that-the-coordinate-functions-determine-the-topology-on-mathcall)).

$(a)$ Write out what a typical element of $\mathcal{L}$ is in terms of subsets of $X$ and the inclusions of sets in other sets.

Could anyone help me in doing so, please?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a link to your previous question, like so: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620392/verify-that-the-coordinate-functions-determine-the-topology-on-mathcall

Comment: @Intergalakti I added the link to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical element of $\mathcal{L}$ is a sequence $(A_n)_n = (A_1, A_2 ,A_3, \ldots)$ obeying:

1. $\forall n: A_n \in \mathcal{A}_n$ (from being in the product of the $\mathcal{A}_n$.)
2. $\forall n: A_{n+1} \subsetneq A_n$ (so they get smaller and smaller), from the fact that $\psi(A_{n+1})=A_n$ and we have *strict* refinements going up.

Then of course, as by all the previous questions we know that all $A_n$ are clopen, non-empty and $\operatorname{diam}(A_n) < \frac1n$, there is a unique $x \in \bigcap_n A_n$ (Cantor intersection theorem, using that all $A_n$ are closed), so we have a map from $\mathcal{L}$ to $X$ (the image of $(A)_n$ being defined by this unique point), and then it's easy to verify that this map is 1-1 and onto and continuous, and so a homeomorphism.

Comment: what is the definition of the map explicitly? I do not understand.

Comment: @Happy it maps the sequence of $A_n$ to its unique intersection point. It's the map $f$ from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3621155/4280).

Comment: In the first line, Is it a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ or a sequence in $A$?

Comment: @Happy a sequence in $\prod_n \mathcal{A}_n$ of course. This is where $A_\infty$ lives.

Comment: No, I mean what you wrote not its definition .... your sequence is in $A_{n}$ not in $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ .... should it be corrected?

Comment: @Happy no, I’m correct.

Comment: ok, could you please, tell me the relation between $\mathcal{A}_{n} $ and $A_{n}$?

Comment: Are we in a complete metric space to use Cantor intersection theorem?

Comment: $A_n$ is a clopen subset of $X$ and a member of the finite partition $\mathcal{A}_n$ of $X$. And $X$ is compact metric so certainly complete.

Comment: Which theorem are you using?

Comment: there is a theorem maybe called nested sequence theorem, does it need completeness?

Comment: @Happy yes, but compactness gives non-empty intersection. The shrinking diameter gives unique point.

Comment: I want to avoid the proof that my space is complete (I do not know how to prove this)?

Comment: @Happy compactness is enough. But completeness is trivial to prove: a. Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsetequence is convergent.

Comment: could you please show me the statement of the theorem that contains compactness only?

Comment: In the first line, why you are writing $(A)_n$ and not  $(A_{n})_n$?

Comment: ohh I understood just now. Is $\mathcal{L} = A_{\infty}$?

Comment: @Happy yes $\mathcal{L}$ is the inverse limit.

Comment: What about my comment before last?

Comment: Also to understand the relation between $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ and  $A_{n}$ Does this means that $\mathcal{A}_{1}.$ contains only   $A_{1}$? I am confused, I am seeing all  $\mathcal{A}_{n}$ the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106670/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-happy).