# Definition of weak-$*$ topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Though I learned some basic theory about topological vector spaces, I always confused about the definition of weak-$*$ topology.

Given $x\in X$, let $\phi_x: X^*\to \Bbb R$ denote the evaluation map $u\to u(x)$ at $x$.

The weak-$*$ topology on $X^*$ is the initial topology associated with the family of all evaluation mpas $\phi_x: X^*\to \Bbb R$. Thus, the weak-$*$ topology is the smallest topology on $X^*$ for which all evaluation maps $\phi_x$ are continuous.

1. What is the definition of initial topology, how to understand the first statement?
2. Why the weak-$*$ topology is the smallest topology on $X^*$ for which all evaluation maps $\phi_x$ are continuous?

3.There is also a conclusion: every subset of $X^*$ which is open for the weak-$*$ topology is also open for the strong topology. (1)

I want to show that $(X^*,SOT)\rightarrow (X^*, \|\cdot \|)$ 
is continuous, but the book I refered mention that "since all evaluation maps are continuous for the strong topology", why can we prove (1) by the reason $"\cdots"$.

Comment: For question 1 you should just look up the definition on wikipedia e.g. For the second question, it's really just a matter of writing out the definition. By definition it is the universal topology such that the evaluation maps are continuous after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I explained the basic theory of initial topologies in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280).

Given a family of functions defined on a set, where the codomain have topologies, we give the set the smallest topology that makes all these functions continuous wrt the already given topologies on the codomains. I prove existence and unicity in that answer.

In your case we have the set $X^\ast$ and all point-evaluation functions $\phi_x$, where $x$ ranges over $X$, and so the common codomain is the field $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$ in the case of complex vector spaces), which has its standard topology.

If we take **all** continuous linear maps from $X^\ast$ (in the norm topology) to $\Bbb R$) we get the weak topology (instead of the weak-star topology) on $X^\ast$; the evaluations are but a small subset of these. We then get a topology in general between (as subsets) the weak-star topology and the norm topology.

This is all general topology theory, but in the case where all $\phi_x$ are linear (as is the case here) and the domain is a vector space, we get a vector space topology on the domain, so that $+$ and scalar multiplication are still continuous on it.

So as to your question 2.: it's true **by definition**. And we choose it because it's useful, e.g. because the closed unit ball is compact in this topology (which can have useful consequences). And as the norm topology is **one** of the topologies that makes all $\phi_x$ continuous by minimality 
$\mathcal{T}_{w\ast} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\textrm{strong}}$ and so the inclusion is continuous. QED.

From the general theory plus some reasoning it follows that the following sets form a base for the open sets of the weak-star topology:

$$B(f; \{x_1, x_2, \ldots,x _n\}, r):= \{g \in X^\ast \mid \forall 1 \le i \le n: |f(x_i) - g(x_i) | < r\}$$

where $f \in X^\ast$, $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a finite subset of $X$ and $r>0$.

This makes it quite concrete as a topology.

Comment: I don't understand why can we get a weak topology by taking all continuous linear maps from $X^*$ to $\Bbb R$. Should the topology be the collection of subsets of $X^*$?

Comment: @mathbeginner I mean the minimal topology that *those* maps are all continuous instead of just the evaluations. Another initial topology.

Answer (score 1):

By initial topology the author means the weakest (coarsest) topology that makes your $\phi_x$ continuous.

To see its the weakest, you just have to write down a topology $\sigma$ that makes all the $\phi_x$ continuous, and realize that the weak topology is contained in this one as well. If you want to be a bit more set theoretical, you can show that the lattice of all topologies on a set $X$ is always complete (i.e all the subsets are bounded above and bellow) under the relation $\tau_2$ is finer (stronger) than $\tau_1$ if $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$. Then, the set off all topologies that make a family $\{ f_\alpha :X\to Y \} $ continuous always has a weakest ( coarsest) topology associated with it.

For 3, consider that the norm topology makes all $\phi_x$ continuous. So the topology it induces is stronger (finer) than the weak* topology by definition of the later. Hence, if a set U is on the weak* topology, it must also be on the strong topology.

Showing the inclusion map is continuous is then just a consequence of the definitions.