# Necessary and sufficient condition of continuity of a function on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subset X$ and $f: Z\longrightarrow A$
> a function. Is it true that $f$ is continuous if and only if the
> function $i \circ f$ is also continuous (where $i: A \hookrightarrow X$
> is the insertion of $A$ into $X$, i.e. $i(x)=x \ \ \ \forall x \in A$)?

This is a homework in my topology class, and I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$i \circ f$ is not defined when $i : A \to X$ and $f: Z \to X$, as the codomain of $f$ is not a always subset of the domain of $i$.

But when it *is* defined (i.e. when $f[Z] \subseteq A$) it will be continuous as a composition of continuous functions.

What **is** true is that

> a function $f:Z \to A$ is continuous iff $ i \circ f: Z \to X$ is continuous.

because $A$ has the [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) w.r.t. $i$. For detailed definitions and proofs see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280).

Quick proof for this special case: if $f$ is continuous so is $i \circ f$ (composition). OTOH, if $i \circ f$ is continuous, let $O$ be open in $A$, i.e. $O= O' \cap A$ for some open $O' \subseteq X$.

Observe that $O' \cap A= i^{-1}[O']$ and the given continuity implies that $(i \circ f)^{-1}[O']$ is open in $Z$ and that set equals $f^{-1}[i^{-1}[O']] = f^{-1}[O]$ and so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry, the function $f$ should be $f:Z \rightarrow A$, I made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that the inclusion and composites of continuous maps are continuous. Once you have established those (or found reference in your course material), it is easy to show that the continuity of $f$ implies that of $f\circ i$. For the converse, consider the inclusion $i\colon \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ and the characteristic function $\chi_\mathbb{Q}\colon\mathbb{R}\to \{0, 1\}$ where $\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the converse is not true?

Comment: Yes. That is my suggestion.

Comment: You should write this in your answer!

Comment: Help for homework =/= immediate answers. Better make them think a bit.

Comment: I am a bit confused, as my question was about the continuity of $i \circ f$, and you are working with $f \circ i$ which is in most cases undefined...