# The continuity of a function between two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces, $A \subset X$, $B \subset Y$
> and $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ a function, such that $f(A) \subset B$.
> Then $f$ determines a function $f|_{A,B} : A \longrightarrow B$.
> Show that:
>
> 1. if $f$ is continuous, then $f|_{A,B}$ is also continuous
> 2. $f$ is continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $f|_{X,f(X)}$ is continuous

This is one of the problems in my topology textbook. I gave it a try but I could not succed. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fact (2.) follows from the fact [we just saw](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833140/4280) applied to $A=f[X]$.

And 1. is easy from definitions: let $O$ be open in $B$, i.e. $O = O' \cap B$ for $O' \subseteq Y$ open.

Then $$(f\restriction_{A,B})^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[O'] \cap A$$

which is open in $A$ by continuiy of $f$ and the definition of the subspace topology on $A$.

Or a bit slicker: Note that: $$i_B \circ f\restriction_{A,B} = f \circ i_A$$ for the respective embeddings of $A$ into $X$ and $B$ into $Y$ which are continuous. Then apply the linked fact for $i_B$.