# About products in $\textbf{Top}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, category-theory

A question about the example below quoted below (Example 5.1.4 from [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf)): Which definition of the product topology does he use? Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition) the product topology to be the coarsest topology for which the projections are continuous. But in the last paragraph of the example below, Leinster refers to this as a "statement", not as a definition. Then, does he use the definition that says that the product topology on $X\times Y$ is the topology whose basis consists of all sets of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$? (That's how Munkres defines the product topology on $X\times Y$.)

If so,  how does the statement that $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ is continuous iff $t\mapsto x(t)$ and $t\mapsto y(t)$ is continuous follow?

One direction seems to be clear: if both one-variable functions are continuous, then the preimage of every open set under $x$ and $y$ is open. It suffices to show that the preimage of a basic open set under $\phi(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is open. Let $U\times V$ be such a set, and consider $\phi^{-1}(U\times V)=\{t:x(t)\in U, y(t)\in V\}$. This is the intersection of the sets  $\{t:x(t)\in U\}$ and $\{t:y(t)\in V\}$, which are open by assumption. So $\phi$ is continuous.

Coversely, if $\phi$ is continuous, we need to show that $\{t:x(t)\in U\}$ and $\{t:y(t)\in V\}$ are both open, where $U$ and $V$ are any open sets in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. We know that $\phi^{-1}(U\times V)=\{t:x(t)\in U, y(t)\in V\}$ is open, but I don't see how this implies that the two sets we're interested in are open.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Look at $\phi^{-1}(U \times Y)$ and $\phi^{-1}(X \times V)$ respectively.

Comment: I see, these sets are precisely the ones for which we need to prove openness.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the universal property for mappings for initial topologies, which I showed and explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280). The map $t \to (f(t), g(t))$ has compositions with the two projections that are precisely $f$ and $g$ which are assumed to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Leinster says that the product topology is designed so that

> A function $f : A \to X \times Y$ is continuous if and only if the two coordinate functions $f_1 : A \to X$ and $f_2 : A \to Y$ are continuous.

This is is not a formal definition, but only a motivational introduction. I do not have access to his book, but I am sure he gives a proper definition later in his text.

Anyway, if we take the above assertion as the characteristic property of a topology on $X \times Y$, we cannot a priori be sure that such a topology *exists* and is *unique*. This requires a proof. How this works is indicated by the statement that the product topology is the smallest topology such that the projections $p_1, p_2$ are continuous. Call a topology making  $p_1, p_2$ continuous an *admissible topology* (this is just an ad-hoc notation). Clearly the discrete topology is admissible and the intersection of all admissible topologies is admissible, thus indeed there exists a (unique) smallest admissible topology. It is easy to see that a basis of this topology is given by the products $U \times V$ of all open $U \subset X, V \subset Y$.

Hence if $f : A \to X \times Y$ is  continuous, then trivially both $f_i = p_i \circ f$ are continuous. Conversely, if the $f_i$ are continuous, we have to prove that $f$ is continuous. To verify that, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(U \times V)$ is open for all basic open $U \times V$. But $U \times V = U \times Y \cap X \times V$ and $f^{-1}(U \times Y \cap X \times V) = f^{-1}(U \times Y) \cap f^{-1}(X \times V) = f_1^{-1}(U) \cap f_2^{-1}( V) $.

Comment: His book is available on ArXiv, and it's linked in the question. I don't think he ever defines the product topology, so he assumes some definition, and I was wondering which one. But apparently this doesn't matter, and I can take any of the two definitions that I mentioned in the question (either via the base or via the coarsest topology that makes the projections continuous)...

Comment: @user634426 I see. His book is about Category Theory, not about Topology. And in fact he just gives an example in $\mathbf{Top}$ without going into details.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your definition of the product topology on $X \times Y$ is that whose open sets are unions of the sets of the form $U \times V$ for $U, V$ open in $X, Y$.

Let $\phi: A \rightarrow X \times Y$ be a continuous function in this sense.  Your question is why the one variable functions $A \rightarrow X \times Y \rightarrow X$ and $A \rightarrow X \times Y \rightarrow Y$ are continuous, correct?

This is obvious from the fact that each of the projections $X \times Y \rightarrow X$ and $X \times Y \rightarrow Y$ are continuous, since a composition of continuous functions remains continuous.

To see that, say, $X \times Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, you need only observe that the preimage of an open set $U \subset X$ is $U \times Y$.