# Proving the universal property of subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, universal-property

I'm asking for feedback on my current work.

**Preamble:** It is known that if $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of functions $f_i:X\to Y_i$, where $(Y_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$ is a topological space, then the topology $\mathcal{T}$ induced by this family is the coarsest topology with which every $f_i:X\to Y_i$ is continuous.

Here's one

**Claim:** Here's one source for the claim, albeit it seems to leave the uniqueness out: [Universal Property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subspace+topology#UniversalProperty)

> Let $X$ be a set and $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of functions $f_i:X\to Y_i$ with $(Y_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$ being a topological space for all $i \in I$. Then the topology $\mathcal{T}$ induced by $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ for $X$ is the only topology for $X$ with the following property: Let $(Z, \mathcal{T}')$ be a topological space and $g:Z\to X$ a function. Then $g$ is continuous iff $f_i\circ g$ is continuous for all $i \in I$.

Suppose that the equivalence of the continuities has already been proven. Therefore, what remains is to show that $\mathcal{T}$ is the only topology with the continuity property.

**My work:** As I've understood the setup, I have to show that if $\mathcal{T}_2$ is any other topology with satisfies the said continuity property, then necessarily $\mathcal{T}_2 = \mathcal{T}$. So let $\mathcal{T}_2$ be such a topology. Since the said property must hold for all $(Z, \mathcal{T}')$ and $g$, we may choose $g = \mathrm{id}, Z = X, \mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T}$.

Then, if $g$ is continuous, it follows that all neighborhoods of $\mathcal{T}_2$ are open in $\mathcal{T}'$, i.e. $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}'$. Since $g$ is continuous then also $f_i \circ g = f_i$ is continuous as well. But since now $f_i$ is continuous w.r.t. $\mathcal{T}_2$ and $\mathcal{T}$ was the coarsest topology with which $f_i$ is continuous, it follows that $\mathcal{T}\subset \mathcal{T}_2$. Hence $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}_2$.

**Thoughts:** Is the argument above enough? I don't think that I've ever proven a claim that some object $X$ is the only one which satisfies an equivalence predicate, so I'm not sure is there more work to do. Namely, I worked through the one way of the equivalence, assuming that $g = \mathrm{id}$ is continuous. Should I also show that $\mathcal{T}_2 = \mathcal{T}$ when it is assumed that $f_i \circ g$ is continuous?

Comment: It seems that your main goal is checking this specific proof - so perhaps ([tag:solution-verification]) would be a suitable tag here. (See [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info) for more details about the usage of this tag.) I think that also ([tag:universal-property]) could fit. It is also worth pointing out that in the title you mention the subspace topology, while the whole post seems to be about the [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).

Comment: I think that you could reorder the statement, and put $\mathcal T$ at the end of the claim, so there would be no confusion on how to prove it. Just like it was mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370174/topology-induced-by-maps-and-continuity-of-g-if-and-only-if-f-i-circ-g-is-c). As Martin Sleziak has said, you are working with the [initial topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818), <- here Henno Brandsma explains very concisely what this is; and in this same answer Henno  proved the unicity.