# Proof for the universal property of initial topology

Tags: general-topology

I wish to prove the following claim:
Let $\tau$ be the initial topology on $X$ induced by the family of maps $\{f_i: X\rightarrow Y_i\}, i\in I$.
Then a map $g: Z\rightarrow X$ is continuous if and only if $f_i\circ g: Z\rightarrow Y_i$ is continuous for all $i\in I$.

I'm having trouble with the opposite direction. I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stack exchange. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/861687.

Comment: @user264745 Thank you!!